# Issue with building an API on top of Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm building a JSON API on top of devise in order to be able to communicate from mobile devices.

So far so good, I am able to create a user account, to get an auth_token. But when I am trying to perform a PUT request, I get some problems , for example the update action for the user. The behavior is really stange, and I can't figure out what is wrong.

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json"  'http://localhost:3000/users' -X PUT -d 'auth_token=A830ALUv7ztTdSfl3qxFgi13BJpEf6VzNYe4yk8rEhVxbYYlOc0YMtTGMxkz&user[name]=plop'
```

Returns

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 02 Mar 2011 06:41:29 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
X-Runtime: 0.157513
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}
```

On the logs on the server i get this .... Really strange.

```
Started PUT "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-03-01 22:41:29 -0800
  Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"auth_token"=>"A830ALUv7ztTdSfl3qxFgi13BJpEf6VzNYe4yk8rEhVxbYYlOc0YMtTGMxkz", "user"=>{"name"=>"plop"}}
Completed   in 1ms
```

Whereas if I modify just the name of the post value from user to users form example, the request works

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 02 Mar 2011 06:43:30 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
ETag: "5e1311709931861e469ce2c8a3b2d0e6"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
Set-Cookie: _u_session=BAh7CEkiGXdhcmRlbi51c2VyLnVzZXIua2V5BjoGRVRbCEkiCVVzZXIGOwBGWwZvOhNCU09OOjpPYmplY3RJZAY6CkBkYXRhWxFpUGGaQG%2FaX1pAfhpAaRpAexpAGkAaQ1JIiIkMmEkMTAkMDVBeDczV29UdVFEZHQxZ1JjN0NXdQY7AFRJjW9uRGlzcGF0Y2g6OkZsYXNoOjpGbGFzaEhhc2h7BjoLbm90aWNlSSIrWW91IHVwZGF0ZWQgeW91ciBhY2NvdW50IHN1Y2Nlc3NmdWxseS4GOwBUBjoKQHVzZWRvOghTZXQGOgpAaGFzaHsASSIPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZAY7AEYiJTcyNmIyZjJiODZhOTBiNjUwZDlhZmIwMzA5MTRkMTlm--0e15953fd7edecb0e08255349c4e55f1eddc8d81; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Runtime: 0.162436
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"redirect":"/","status":"ok"}
```

I precise that, even without my code(For the API) I can't perform this request !!!!

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that Devise handles JSON calls, there is an [open issue on github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues#issue/786) that is scheduled for the 1.3 release to address this problem.